# Using result of a function as search conditional

Tags: python, function

I would like to insert the 1st result of the function `def elliptic()` into the 2nd function `entity_noun()`. In the 2nd function, it finds the node which has the attribute with a specific value. I want this value (which is a string in quotes `"??????"`) to be retrieved from the returned value of the 1st function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def elliptic():
    last_a_tag = soup.find_all("sn", elliptic="yes")
    for item in last_a_tag:
            entity = item.get('entity')  
    return(entity)

def entity_noun():
    ent = soup.find(entity="??????")    
    noun = ent.find('n')
    return(noun)
```

Do you have any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: ent = soup.find(entity=elliptic())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the result of calling the function right in the parameters.

So in this case you would do:

```
ent = soup.find(entity=elliptic())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have here two functions. function should be called to return a result.
if you do something like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def elliptic():
    last_a_tag = soup.find_all("sn", elliptic="yes")
    for item in last_a_tag:
            entity = item.get('entity')  
    return(entity)

def entity_noun():
    ent = soup.find(entity=elliptic())    
    noun = ent.find('n')
    return(noun)

entity_noun()
```

you will call `entity_noun()` which will call `elliptic()`

an other option is to use argument :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def elliptic():
    last_a_tag = soup.find_all("sn", elliptic="yes")
    for item in last_a_tag:
            entity = item.get('entity')  
    return(entity)

def entity_noun(X):
    ent = soup.find(entity=X)    
    noun = ent.find('n')
    return(noun)

A=elliptic()
entity_noun(A)
```

in this case you will call the first function `elliptic()` keep the result in `A` and then pass `A` to `entity_noun()`. with this second method each function will stay independent one from an other and so be used independently in different context.